# Validation Error GraphQL gql query string

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I'm trying to execute this mutation through executeOperation, but I'd like to reuse later the info that I send in the mutation as GiftcardRestriccionInput.

```
const result = await apolloServer.executeOperation({
        query: gql`mutation {
          addGiftcardRestriccion(GiftcardRestriccionInput: 
            id_giftcard: 22,
        id_empresa: 2,
        restricciones: [
          {
            nombre: "sucursal",
            label: "debe indicar la sucursal donde retirar la tarjeta",
            descripcion: "alguna descripcion extra",
            prop: "seleccion_simple"
          }
        ]
          ) {
            status,
            message
            data {
              id_giftcard
              id_empresa
              restricciones {
                descripcion
                nombre
                label
                prop
              }
            }
          }
        }`
      });
```

So what I'd like to do is save the data in a const variable and then pass it with string interpolation (${})

I get this error `[[ValidationError: Expected value of type "GiftcardRestriccionInput", found [object, Object].]]`

```
const data = {
        id_giftcard: 22,
        id_empresa: 2,
        restricciones: [
          {
            nombre: "sucursal",
            label: "debe indicar la sucursal donde retirar la tarjeta",
            descripcion: "alguna descripcion extra",
            prop: "seleccion_simple"
          }
        ]
      }

      const result = await apolloServer.executeOperation({
        query: gql`mutation {
          addGiftcardRestriccion(GiftcardRestriccionInput: 
            ${data}
          ) {
            status,
            message
            data {
              id_giftcard
              id_empresa
              restricciones {
                descripcion
                nombre
                label
                prop
              }
            }
          }
        }`
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to inject the variables as strings just use the `variables` parameter in [apolloServer.executeOperation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/testing/testing/#executeoperation):

```
const gcri = {
  id_giftcard: 22,
  id_empresa: 2,
  etc…
  }

const result = await apolloServer.executeOperation({
  query: gql`mutation agcr($gcri: yourInputType) {
    addGiftcardRestriccion(GiftcardRestriccionInput: $gcri) {
      status,
      message,
      …additional fields
    }`,
  variables: gcri
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Variable "$giftcardRestriccion" of required type "GiftcardRestriccionInput!" was not provided.` 

{
          query: gql`mutation adicionar_giftcardRestriccion($giftcardRestriccion: GiftcardRestriccionInput!) {
            addGiftcardRestriccion(GiftcardRestriccionInput: $giftcardRestriccion) {
              status,
              message
            }
          }`,
          variables: giftcardRestriccion
        }

  `let giftcardRestriccion: GiftcardRestriccionInput = { fields }`

Comment: It was an easy wraping of variables object 
`variables: { giftcardRestriccion }`
I was actually not sending variables lol